# Salesforce Professional Edition: Opportunity Stage Type field

Tags: reporting, custom-field

[image: OpportunityStageEditPage]

Salesforce Professional Edition:  Where/How can I access this Opportunity Stage Type field to add to layouts or reporting. Logged cases with premier support and they don't know Case #17755136 and #17756433 one with Reporting other Analytics. Now, asking you... the developers.

Answer (score 2):

The "Type" isn't directly exposed on the Opportunity, but instead displayed as two fields: "IsWon" and "IsClosed". As such, you could make a formula field (type TEXT) to display a suitable result:

```
IF(IsClosed, IF(IsWon, "Closed/Won", "Closed/Lost"), "Open")
```